How create HyperLink to local bookmark with JS in OnlyOffice pugin? (href=#bookmarkname)
friends. I am unable to create a valid bookmark link in the document.
ApiRange.AddHyperlink(sLink, sScreenTipText) → { ApiHyperlink | null }
with sLink = ‘#bookmarkname’ not create correct link.
I tried to make a hyperlink out of the highlighted text
const makeBookmark = (bookmarkName, text, document) => {
    const range = document.Search(text, false)[0];
    range.AddBookmark(bookmarkName);
    const currentSelect = oDocument.GetRangeBySelect();
    currentSelect.AddHyperlink(`#${bookmarkName}`, `#${bookmarkName}`);
                        
}

When clicking on this link, the cursor does not move to the bookmark.
